# Assigning values to cells in excel such that their sum is a constant

Tags: excel

Is there  a way to assign values in 5 cells in excel such that the sum of the 5 cells is exactly 100?

I started with assigning each cell a value `20`. But I want the cells to change values if I assign one of them value 30

Comment: We need a little more information, as there are literally infinite solutions to your problem right now. For example, you could change one cell to 30, and then have the other cells as (0, 0, 0, 70) or (-30, -999, 999, 100). Do you want the other cells to remain equal? Or do you only want one other cell to change at a time? Can it be the same cell that changes each time? The solution also depends on how many of the cells you want to be able to change... 1 of them? 2 of them? or all of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your 5 cells are in rows 1 to 5, I would use the following **Worksheet_Change** event to track the values will always add up to 100.

**Example:**

Initial data set:

[image]

Solution after value in field A3 has been changed to 78:

[image]

Note that the code as to be pasted in the Objects of the sheet you are tracking the numbers on.

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim averageRound As Variant, averageRound1 As Variant

    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Or IsEmpty(Target) Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    averageRound = Application.WorksheetFunction.Round((100 - Application.Sum(Range(Cells(1, Target.Column), Cells(5, Target.Column)))) / 4, 0)


        If ((100 - Application.Sum(Range(Cells(1, Target.Column), Cells(5, Target.Column)))) + averageRound * 4) <> 100 Then
            averageRound1 = (100 - Application.Sum(Range(Cells(1, Target.Column), Cells(5, Target.Column)))) - averageRound * 3
        Else
            averageRound1 = averageRound
        End If

    If IsNumeric(Target) Then
        If Application.Sum(Range(Cells(1, Target.Column), Cells(5, Target.Column))) <> 100 Then

            If Target.Row = 1 Then
                Cells(Target.Row + 1, Target.Column).Value = Cells(Target.Row + 1, Target.Column).Value + averageRound
                Cells(Target.Row + 2, Target.Column).Value = Cells(Target.Row + 2, Target.Column).Value + averageRound
                Cells(Target.Row + 3, Target.Column).Value = Cells(Target.Row + 3, Target.Column).Value + averageRound
                Cells(Target.Row + 4, Target.Column).Value = Cells(Target.Row + 4, Target.Column).Value + averageRound1
            ElseIf Target.Row = 2 Then
                Cells(Target.Row - 1, Target.Column).Value = Cells(Target.Row - 1, Target.Column).Value + averageRound
                Cells(Target.Row + 1, Target.Column).Value = Cells(Target.Row + 1, Target.Column).Value + averageRound
                Cells(Target.Row + 2, Target.Column).Value = Cells(Target.Row + 2, Target.Column).Value + averageRound1
                Cells(Target.Row + 3, Target.Column).Value = Cells(Target.Row + 3, Target.Column).Value + averageRound
            ElseIf Target.Row = 3 Then
                Cells(Target.Row - 2, Target.Column).Value = Cells(Target.Row - 2, Target.Column).Value + averageRound
                Cells(Target.Row - 1, Target.Column).Value = Cells(Target.Row - 1, Target.Column).Value + averageRound1
                Cells(Target.Row + 1, Target.Column).Value = Cells(Target.Row + 1, Target.Column).Value + averageRound
                Cells(Target.Row + 2, Target.Column).Value = Cells(Target.Row + 2, Target.Column).Value + averageRound
            ElseIf Target.Row = 4 Then
                Cells(Target.Row - 3, Target.Column).Value = Cells(Target.Row - 3, Target.Column).Value + averageRound
                Cells(Target.Row - 2, Target.Column).Value = Cells(Target.Row - 2, Target.Column).Value + averageRound
                Cells(Target.Row - 1, Target.Column).Value = Cells(Target.Row - 1, Target.Column).Value + averageRound1
                Cells(Target.Row + 1, Target.Column).Value = Cells(Target.Row + 1, Target.Column).Value + averageRound
            ElseIf Target.Row = 5 Then
                Cells(Target.Row - 1, Target.Column).Value = Cells(Target.Row - 1, Target.Column).Value + averageRound
                Cells(Target.Row - 2, Target.Column).Value = Cells(Target.Row - 2, Target.Column).Value + averageRound
                Cells(Target.Row - 3, Target.Column).Value = Cells(Target.Row - 3, Target.Column).Value + averageRound
                Cells(Target.Row - 4, Target.Column).Value = Cells(Target.Row - 4, Target.Column).Value + averageRound1
            End If

        End If
    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be able to change any of the 5 cells, and have the others recalculate, you would need a complex forumla depending on the cell location and surrounding cells.

You would determine the difference of the other 4 cells from 100 and then distribute that difference equally over the other 4 cells. Of course, when you manually change one cell, you will wipe out it's forumla, so it will only work once.

To make it permanent, you would need a VBA script that monitors a range of cells and does the adjustments for you.

If you're happy with have only one cell dynamically change to maintain the balance, then it is more simple. You can have that cell be the 100 minus the sum of the other 4 cells.